# Merge Sort implementation - Duplicate values error

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, collections, mergesort

I am trying to implement Merge Sort in Java based on various tutorials available online but my resulted list has duplicate values. After much debugging, I am still not able to find out what's wrong in my implementation.
Following is the code:

```
 public  ArrayList<Integer> mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> whole)
 {
    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int center;
    if(whole.size() ==1 ) return whole;

    else
    {
        center =  whole.size()/2;

        for(int i = 0; i < center; i++  )
        {
            left.add(whole.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = center ; i < whole.size(); i++  )
        {
            right.add(whole.get(i));
        }

        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);

      whole =   merge(left, right, whole);
     return whole;
    }


 }


private  ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> left, ArrayList<Integer> right, ArrayList<Integer> whole) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int leftIn = 0;
    int rightIn = 0;
    int wholeIn = 0;

    while( leftIn <left.size() && rightIn < right.size())
    {
        if(left.get(leftIn).compareTo(right.get(rightIn)) < 0)
        {
            whole.set(wholeIn, left.get(leftIn));

            leftIn++;
        }
        else 
        {
            whole.set(rightIn, right.get(rightIn));

            rightIn++;
        }
        wholeIn++;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> rest;
    int restIn;
    if(leftIn >= left.size())
    {
        rest = right;
        restIn = rightIn;
    }
    else
    {
        rest = left;
        restIn = leftIn;
    }

    for(int i = restIn ; i < rest.size(); i++)
    {       
        whole.set(wholeIn, rest.get(i));
        wholeIn++;
    }
    return whole;

}
```

Input List:  1  5  -2  98  -221  3  8   7

Output :  -221  3   7   8     5  3  8  98

Comment: You don't have duplicate values, you have values being *overwritten*.  i.e. your input contains {1, -2} both of which are missing in the output and instead have an extra 3 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` method is accidentally using the wrong index `rightIn` in the `else` case of the `while` loop.  This can lead to overwritten values, manifesting in missing values and duplicate values.

Use `wholeIn` like the `if` case does.  Change

```
whole.set(rightIn, right.get(rightIn));
```

to

```
whole.set(wholeIn, right.get(rightIn));
```